# Angularjs retrieving data issue while sending data by post

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-http

I send an id that I get from url to the server (php page).

The way I get from url and send by `post` method in angularjs:

(**NOTE :**  I retrieve data and in console.log() it prints alright, the problem is where I want to put them into **$scope** )

```
.controller('PlaylistCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $http) {
    $http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://cms.focusweb.ir/Json/get_article',
        data: { id: $stateParams.playlistId },
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    })
    .success(function(response) {
        // This works right
        console.log(response);
        // PROBLEM IS HERE
        angular.forEach(response, function(response){
            $scope.articles_content.push(response);
        });

    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // handle error things
    });
});
```

My PHP code is:

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
$article_ID = $request->id;
```

The error I get is:

[image: Error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is basically saying `articles_content` doesn't exist (`undefined`). Hence `'push' of undefined`

You need to define your array before trying to use it.

`$scope.articles_content = []`

So should be:

```
 .controller('PlaylistCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $http) {

    $scope.articles_content = []; // Add this in here


    $http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://cms.focusweb.ir/Json/get_article',
            data: { id: $stateParams.playlistId },
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        })
        .success(function(response) {
            // This works right
            console.log(response);

            angular.forEach(response, function(response){
              // because you now defined articles_content 
              // as an array, the push() will now work :)
              $scope.articles_content.push(response);
            });

        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // handle error things
        });
    });
```

The `$scope` has already been defined, which is why you can dynamically add anything to it. Anything deeper than this, you need to define your structure first.